# Como puedo usar un combo box de html para AJAX

Tags: javascript, html5, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

Buen día, tengo el problema de una calculadora que estoy elaborando usando AJAX ya que quiero hacer la operación y que el resultado se muestre en el SPAN RESULTADO pero no logro hacer que el script funcione y pienso que la problematica esta ahi y en el combo box para que tome la operacion que el usuario desee. Les adjunto parte del codigo junto con el home controller.

```
                     <div class="col-md-4">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Valor A</label>

                            <input type="number" name="a" step="any" class="form-control" value="" id="txtDato1" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Valor B</label>

                            <input type="number" name="b" step="any" class="form-control" value="" id="txtDato2"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Operacion</label>
                            <select typeof="text" name="c" class="form-control" value="" id="txtOperacion">
                                <option value="suma">Suma</option>
                                <option value="resta">Resta</option>
                                <option value="multiplicación">Multiplicación</option>

                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-control-static">
                            <input type="button" value="Resultado" id="btnResultado"/>
                        </div>
                        Resultado: <span id="spanResultado"></span>
                    </div>
```

Este es el script:

```
<script>
//Accion al apretar el boton de resultado
$("#btnResultado").click(function () {
    var url = "@Url.Action("Resultado", "Home")";
    var cantidad1 = $("#txtDato1").val();
    var cantidad2 = $("#txtDato2").val();
    var operacion = $("#txtOperacion").val();
    var data = { a: cantidad1, b: cantidad2, c: operacion };

    //jQuery
    $.post(url, data).done(function (data){
        $("#spanResultado").html(data);
    }).fail(manejarErrorAjax).always(function () {
    });

    function manejarErrorAjax(err) {
    console.log(err.responseText);
}    
});
```

Y este la operacion json que tengo en el home controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Resultado(string a, string b, string c)
    {
        var Resultado = 0.0;
        switch (c)
        { 
            case "suma":
                Resultado= float.Parse(a) + float.Parse(b);

                break;
            case "resta":
               Resultado =  float.Parse(a) - float.Parse(b);
                break;

            case "mutiplicacion":

                Resultado= float.Parse(a) * float.Parse(b);
                break;



        }
        return Json(Resultado);


    }
```

Espero puedan ayudarme muchas gracias.

Comment: Te faltaq el **#** en $("btnResultado")

Answer (score 1):

Alexis, respetando el estilo de cada persona al programar, pero lo que yo haría primero seria utilizar una función que "escuche" el cambio del selector este código me sirve para eso

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Nombre del select").on('change', function () {
        $("#Nombre del selec option:selected").each(function () {
            $('input[name=Nombre input]').val($(this).val());
        });
   });
});
```

En este caso el valor obtenido lo envía a un input, en tu caso lo podrías pasar por parametro al archivo donde tienes el case para que cargue la operación matemática seleccionada.

Es una idea..

Saludos

P.D. le quite una linea ya que esa linea la utilizo para cargar el valor en una variable y luego me la imprima en pantalla como alerta para verificar que hizo la función de escucha y asignación al input.

Te pongo la función completa donde captura el valor y lo envia a la pantalla para que la puedas comparar

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Nombre_select").on('change', function () {
        $("#Nombre_select option:selected").each(function () {
            var Nombre_select = $(this).val();
            alert (Nombre_select);
            $('input[name=Personal]').val($(this).val());
        });
   });
});
```